# Another 3 monitor eyefinity issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, eyefinity

I've been looking around the web, and I have yet to get a *conclusive* answer to this question.

I have purchased a Radeon HD 6970 and I want to run 3 monitors off of it. The monitors I am using take only VGA or DVI. The 6970 has 2x DVI, 2x Mini DisplayPort, and a single HDMI port. Clearly I'll use DVI-DIV-x... But what do I use for the last monitor? I've heard there are some issues with using HDMI to DVI passive converters... Does anyone have a definitive answer to this?

Preferably, I'd like to be able to use HDMI with something like this [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000E8SY5Q/ref=oh_o00_s00_i00_details](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000E8SY5Q).

Comment: Ok - I've found a definitive answer. The config on multi monitor setups MUST be DVI-DIV-DP. Essentially, the 6970 cannot use both DVI and HDMI for Eyefinity. http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004071ZXA?tag=vglnk-c1001-20 is a probably a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I work in a Dell Shop and I use the Display Port to DVI adapters all the time, they work just fine.  I can't see why the mini DPs would be any different.

http://www.bing.com/shopping/search?q=dell+mini+display+port+to+dvi&qpvt=dell+mini+display+port+to+dvi&FORM=HURE

Knock yerself out Kiddo.

Comment: I shoulda just said yes, use the link you posted, it's just fine.